# Testing synchronous code

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I have a section of code that is using [node-sync](https://github.com/ybogdanov/node-sync) like so:

```
function funcA() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    Sync(function () {
      return funcB.sync();
    }, function (err, result) {
      if(err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(result);
      }
    });
}
```

This code is tested using mocha+chai:

```
it("should return array", function() {
  return funcA().then(function(result) {
    expect(result).to.be.an.instanceof(Array);
  });
});
```

It worked just fine couple of months ago, but now this test always times out:

> Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.

What I've tried so far:

- using `done()` instead of returning a promise
- replacing `node-sync` with `synchronize.js`
- increasing timeout

What I found out, is that `expect(...` part of this test is, in fact, being called, but only after mocha kills the test. No matter what timeout interval is currently set, `expect(..` is being called always ~20 milliseconds after I get `Error: timeout` message.

I fixed the issue by adding `setInterval(function(){}, 10)` on the top of the test file. **I'd like to know why this worked and if there is some better way to fix that?**

[EDIT] It looks like this is a node-version specific issue. Test fails on 0.12.4 but runs correctly on 0.10.38 .

[EDIT] Actual code is available [here](https://github.com/kdzwinel/Proofreader).

Comment: Seems very odd..  i can reproduce it but can't figure out what the issue is.  might be a long shot but maybe dig into node-sync , see these github tickets [here](https://github.com/ybogdanov/node-sync/issues/41)  and  [here](https://github.com/ybogdanov/node-sync/issues/36)

Comment: btw it's typically best practice (imho) to not run code asynchronously in a test.  I know you're attempting to run this block sync, but maybe try the chai-as-promised module so you can remove the `done`

Answer (score 2):

Based on your [code](https://github.com/kdzwinel/Proofreader/blob/master/lib/proofreader.js#L122), I am assuming that your funcB function is running code in a **synchronous way**.

So when I create funcB in this way:

```
function funcB() {
  return [1, 2, 3];
}
```

And run the test, Mocha shows an error:

> Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.

But if I convert the funcB in **asynchronus function** as this:

```
function funcB(cb) {
  process.nextTick(function () {
    cb(null, [1, 2, 3]);
  });
}
```

Mocha runs the test without any problem:

> ✓ should return an array

---

So my complete code that runs ok (the funcB commented is the one that will cause the error) is this:

```
// install dependencies
// npm install promise
// npm install sync
var Promise = require('promise');
var assert = require('assert');
var Sync = require('sync');

function funcA() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    Sync(function () {
      return funcB.sync();
    }, function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(result);
      }
    });
  });
}

// function funcB() {
//   return [1, 2, 3];
// }

function funcB(cb) {
  process.nextTick(function () {
    cb(null, [1, 2, 3]);
  });
}

it("should return an array", function(done) {
  return funcA().then(
    function (result) {
      console.log(result);
      assert.equal(Array.isArray(result), true);
      done();
    }
  );
});
```

So I am opinion I think that the misuse of the [sync method](https://github.com/ybogdanov/node-sync/blob/master/lib/sync.js#L27) (using it on synchronous functions) created by sync library is the one that is causing this problem.

Comment: Hey Wilson! Thank you for this, but it is still a hack and it doesn't answer why this happens. I'm guessing that my use of `setInterval` serves exact same purpose as your `nextTick` hack. It seems that node goes "asleep" and needs to be woken up by `nextTick` or `setInterval`. The question is, why this happens and if that's a node issue, Sync issue or an expected behaviour? I'd love to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong but reasoning from the doc of the [method](https://github.com/ybogdanov/node-sync/blob/master/lib/sync.js#L27) that says: *"sync() method simply turns any asynchronous function to synchronous one"* so calling this method from a sync function like funcB, to me could be potentially the source of the bug.

Answer (score 1):

You may just be missing the `done()` callback:

```
it("should return array", function(done) {
    funcA().then(function(result) {
        expect(result).to.be.an.instanceof(Array);
        done();
    });
});
```

http://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code

Comment: Hey, thanks for suggestion - as mentioned in question I already tried `done()`. Also, returning a promise should work just fine (in fact you linked to the very section in mocha docs where this is described). My issue seems to be node-version related.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a timeout parameter for mocha executable.

For example, if you want a 500 milliseconds timeout, just change your `package.json` to:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha specs --timeout 500 --require specs/helpers/chai.js"
},
```

And maybe your promise is being rejected, so you have to call `done` using `catch` method.

```
it("should return array", function(done) {
    return funcA().then(function(result) {
        expect(result).to.be.an.instanceof(Array);
        done();
    }).catch(done);
});
```

This would also help you debug eventual errors that might happen in your promise code.

Comment: Hey! As mentioned in the question, I've tried increasing timeout - the test fails *always* right after the timeout (no matter what the timeout value is). Having catch is a good tip, but this test doesn't fail, it times out.

Comment: @KonradDzwinel Hmm.. It seems you're trying to test a code with promises that does everything in the same process. Try changing `setTimeout()` to `process.nextTick();` and check if it still works. Also, can you send the code of the method you're trying to test?

Comment: Hey! Whole thing is available [here](https://github.com/kdzwinel/Proofreader). Tests pass on node 0.10 but fail on 0.12. I will try changing setInterval to nextTick later on. My guess is that it will work - the question is why I have to trigger next tick manually in node 0.12?